# [PHP-PDO What is making my query slowdown?

Tags: mysql

We are working on a private forum solution and we have a table of "posts" which has :

1. 1 index (primary key)
2. Unique key ( i.e. slug / seo-url of the respective post )
3. 2 FOREIGN Keys ( Refering Category(id) and user(id) for category of post and OP of the post.

Now, the ID ( Primary key), category (id) and user(id) are all INT(11) UNSIGNED and we have used the following and we get the results in 0.2XX seconds (on PHP page):

- Using PHP PDO
- Using PHP-MySQLi
- Using PHP PDO with Persistent connection and buffered queries

Query: Both give almost same performance (in range of 0.17-0.2XX seconds)

1. Select rows from post,category,user where post.userid=user.id and post.categoryid=category.id and post.id=1; -> Gives result in 0.17 to 0.28 seconds on average
2. SELECT wors FROM post INNER JOIN category
   on post.categoryid = category.id INNER JOIN user on post.userid = user.id -> a tag bid faster than earlier but still on slower part.

Now when we use MyBB or PHPBB , as a part of testing, those things load up *all* the queries including selecting sessions, updating that row and inserting within  0.2 seconds. what exactly are those softwares doing?

We used PDO  Connection, Prepare, then bind then execute.same for MySQLi.

As a forward step, I created a view with all necessary columns from all 3 tables in one view but that again gives same performance.

What am I doing wrong, a single query takes up 0.18-0.2XX seconds whereas a complete page gets displayed (with more than 1 select+update+select) faster.

Case: MyBB / PHPBB and the customised forum were all used on same machine with same PHP-MySQL configuration and only 2 users simulataneously accessing the site (1 user with 2 different browsers)

Answer (score 0):

> What am I doing wrong

You are looking in completely wrong direction. Every measure you took has nothing to do with query performance.

What you have to do is to study the `EXPLAIN` output for the given queries, and set indexes accordingly, to make these queries use indexes for all tables involved.

Comment: hi, What indexes do you suggest? I am looking into tables and all tables have one default BTREE INDEX which happens to be the primary key respectively and post table has 4 indexes i.e. of all primary keys, unique ones and foreign keys.